# Erro usando o curl PHP

Tags: php

Tenho um sistema que tem **2** tipos de acessos. Um para o Administrador e o outro para Usuários, os cadastros constam na mesma tabela, mudando apenas o Status.

> Ex.: Administrador = A e Usuários = U.

Porém tenho que fazer uma integração a um sistema externo, do qual estou usando a `curl` do *PHP* para isso.

Aí que vem a dúvida. Como uso a mesma tabela, verificando apenas o status na hora do acesso, então pego dessa forma:

```
$dadosUsuario = array( 
        "user_id"       => $usuario->id_usuario,
        "name"          => $_SESSION['NomeUsuario'],
        .....
        );
```

E em seguida:

```
$data_string = json_encode($dadosUsuario);
$curl = curl_init('https://www.site-da-integracao.com.br/usuarios/'); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);  

$result = curl_exec($curl);
$error = curl_error($curl);
$response = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($curl);
```

Só que quando acesso como administrador, a validação ocorre normalmente, mas como usuário, diz que o nome está vazio. Só que darmos o `print_r()` na variável `$dadosUsuario` o nome aparece...

Alguém sabe o porque disso acontecer?

Comment: Amigo o seu problema parece ser com acento e não com status do usuário, verifique se o usuário que esta testando tem acento no nome. 
Altere o seu código. Em vez de: json_encode($dadosUsuario);
Use: json_encode($dadosUsuario, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

Comment: Olá Euler...coloquei, mas aparece o mesmo erro: 
{"error":"ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid - A validação falhou: Nome não pode ficar em branco"}

Comment: faz o seguinte da um exit($data_string) logo depois do json_encode e manda o que retorna

Comment: "user_id":"6024","name":"guilherme nunes","first_name":"guilherme","surname":"nunes"

Comment: Estranho mesmo...pq o name está preenchido... só acontece com o usuário... com o adm funciona perfeitamente

Comment: esse é do adm: "user_id":"4912","name":"fabio antonio","first_name":"fabio","surname":"antonio"

Comment: Cara da uma olhada no seu Server que esta recebendo a requisição se é algum problema na validação, as vezes o problema é em outro campo, mas a mensagem está errada.

Comment: Desculpe Euler... nao consegui entender...

Comment: Onde é feita a validação do usuário? Na página externa?